Python Selenium Web Scraping by Class Name
The code cannot scrape the web to get the links. The website is: https://www.carrefour.com.ar/Almacen
and there is always an error related with no such element. I tried with wait and points instead of spaces without luck.
# Navigate to the page
driver.get('https://www.carrefour.com.ar/almacen')

#wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

div_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "recs_18369321")

a_tags = div_element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')

links = [a.get_attribute('href') for a in a_tags]


no class name 'recs_18369321', the name is dynamic
